# jQuery check if <li> cointains 2 img tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check if the single `li` tag cointains single or 2 `img` tags and run the jQuery script only if there are 2 `img` tags. Now when a single `li` contains only one image it disappear after click.

It should work follow:

1. On load - show first image, hide second image
2. On click - First image hide, show second image
3. Click on the Second image - Second image hide, show first image

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#list-of-images li img:first-child").click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).next().show();
    });
     $("list-of-images li img:nth-child(2)").click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).prev().show();
    });
});
```

```css
#list-of-images li img:nth-child(2) { 
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list-of-images">
<li>
<img src="https://cdn.infobeamer.com/s/6bd893/img/hosted-restaurant.png" />
<img src="https://cdn.infobeamer.com/s/e67487/img/hosted-your-usecase.png" />
</li>

<li>
<img src="https://cdn.infobeamer.com/s/6bd893/img/hosted-restaurant.png" />
<img src="https://cdn.infobeamer.com/s/e67487/img/hosted-your-usecase.png" />
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first check the length image in clicked `li`.

Check if the length of next `img` is greater then 0 or not. If it is true show next else show previous image.

```js
$("#list-of-images li img").click(function () {
  if($(this).parent().find('img').length == 2) {
    $(this).hide();
    if($(this).next('img').length> 0)
      $(this).next('img').show();
    else
      $(this).prev('img').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#list-of-images li img:nth-child(2) { 
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list-of-images">
<li>
<img src="https://cdn.infobeamer.com/s/6bd893/img/hosted-restaurant.png" />
<img src="https://cdn.infobeamer.com/s/e67487/img/hosted-your-usecase.png" />
</li>

<li>
<img src="https://cdn.infobeamer.com/s/6bd893/img/hosted-restaurant.png" />
<img src="https://cdn.infobeamer.com/s/e67487/img/hosted-your-usecase.png" />
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.